# InDesign: hard return to move to the next text frame?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, typesetting, formatting

Is there a way to set a hard return to move to the next text frame, so if I copied a page of text, every hard return would move to the next text frame that I have threaded?

Comment: A quick way to get this effect is to use Enter on the numpad. However, Horribly_n00bie's answer to build it into a style is a better practice.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a column break character via the **keypad** <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of the normal <kbd>Enter/Return</kbd>, and this basicly jumps to the next linked frame.

Or, assuming each page should work as a single paragraph, paste your content as you normally would, then use find/change to replace every 'End of Paragraph' with a 'Column Break' (see below).

[image]

Comment: You're edit answered my next question.

Comment: Alright so the find and replace, is manual. I found that in my paragraph styles -> keep options -> I can select, "Start Paragraph: In Next Frame" This automatically takes the hard return and flows it properly, but your answer lead me on the path to this automation. Thank you!

Comment: Oh right, well spotted.

Comment: I have one small question about the paragraph styles. There is a way to have each end of paragraph automatically select a specific paragraph style, but I'm having trouble wording the question to find out how to set that up. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not sure i know what your referring to. Is that a next style?

Comment: Yeah. I'm having trouble wording it right. I set up 3 types of text frames and 3 paragraph styles. Title, Sub-Title, Paragraph. So the way I would be getting copy would be "Title¶ Subtitle¶ paragraph¶ Subtitle¶ paragraph..." So I want to make InDesign automatically apply the correct style for the story. I've seen it done before, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: You probably need to read about Next Styles here https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/paragraph-character-styles.html or via Google/Youtube.

Comment: You can also use Shift + Enter, which is a frame break, rather than a column break (at least that’s the default Mac shortcut).

Answer (score 4):

With much help from Lucian I have figured out a succinct way of accomplishing what I needed to do:

1. make the paragraph styles I want to use.
2. in the paragraph styles, under the "Keep Options" select "Start Paragraph: In Next Frame"
3. in the paragraph styles again, under "General" select "Next Style:____"

You can set the next style to have a starting point and then after a specific style you can have it loop back.